TypeError: Job.create is not a function
I'm using sequelize in my project, and importing the Job(variable connected to the database) from the models folder, but when I use Job.create it returns this error when inserting data into postman:
TypeError: Job.create is not a function
I checked the connection with the database, and it's working, but Job.create doesn't work.
code:
**//in models at Jobs.js file**
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db/connection');
//Define
const Job = db.define('job', {
    title:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,

    },
    description:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    salary:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    company:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    new_job:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    }
});

**// in routes at job.js file**
const express = require('express');
const router  = express.Router();
const Job = require('../models/Job')
//test
router.get('/test',(req, res)=>{
    res.send("As rotas estão funcionando");
})
//add
router.post("/add", (req, res)=>{
    let {title, salary, company, description, email, new_job} = req.body;
    //insert 
    Job.create({
        title,
        salary,
        company,
        description,
        email,
        new_job
    })
    .then(()=>{
        res.redirect('/');
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;



I solved it, I had forgotten to give module.exports = Job
;-;

I solved it, I had forgotten to give module.exports = Job ;-;
